# is it possible to set a variable value using an if statement?

Tags: ios, swift

in kotlin you can do this

```
val height = if height > 3.0 {
    return "giant"
} else {
    return "regular"
}
```

that is setting the value of a variable or constant using an if statement

is it possible to do the same thing in swift?

```
let height = if height > 3.0 {
    return "giant"
} else {
    return "regular"
}
```

I tried this for swift but i get `Expected initial value after '='` error

Comment: I guess for your current code no need to a variable as you already has a return or may be you do something like `return height` at end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ternary operator in Swift

```
return height > 3.0 ? "giant" : "regular"
```

Also in  Kotlin you can do

```
return if(height > 3.0) "giant" else "regular"
```

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to use a ternary:

```
let heightClass = height > 3.0 ? "giant" : "regular"
```

You can also define the variable first and then assign it within the statement:

```
let heightClass : String
if height > 3.0 {
   heightClass = "giant"
} else {
   heightClass = "regular"
}
```

And (this is probably my least favorite):

```
let heightClass : String = {
  if height > 3.0 {
    return "giant"
  } else {
    return "regular"
  }
}()
```

Comment: your last example is quite interesting, haven't seen that before, could you please explain it a bit

Comment: I interpreted your question as you wanted to set a variable based on a condition -- not return a value, so these all relate to that scenario. Looks like the accepted answer is just about returning values though -- sorry if I got the purpose wrong.

Comment: yes you're right, i wanted to set a variable based on a condition, you're first example, solves that, and if it had come in first i would have easily accepted the answer and it's also correct, although your second example isn't what i'm trying to do but rather what i'm trying to avoid

Comment: i'm not sure what your last exampe is doing but it looks like it's running on a thread?

Comment: The last example defines a closure and runs it immediately. It won't be on a different thread -- it just gets inlined with the rest of the code. It's main convenience (in my mind) is that you can define a new scope by doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is allowed now in Swift as of Swift 5.9:

```
let height = 4.0

let heightStr = if height > 1.0 && height <= 2.0 { "small" }
    else if height > 1.0 && height <= 2.0  { "medium" }
    else { "large" }

print(heightStr)
```

See

- https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0380-if-switch-expressions.md
- https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift/5.9/if-switch-expressions